# How to enable search in documents in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Do I need to enable something or run indexing or some service so the documents appear in the search results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to configure an indexing job, here is how:

> After installing the system you need to configure your indexing job. Navigate to CA, Service Applications, Search. You will see a link to your Content Sources. If you edit that it will give you the opportunity to setup a schedule for both Full and Incremental indexing. You can kick off a full drawl, once completed you will have results if everything is configured correctly.

Source: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/3531/sharepoint-2010-search-not-working

Comment: It just worked by itself after a while. I guess after the time interval for the period was over.