# Search A For A Document Library or Document In a Document Library in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

I am new to Share Point.  I created a Document Library and added a number of documents to that library.  When I use the "Search" feature, I enter the exact name of a document in that document library, but I contiue to get no results.  I don't understand why?  Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Your administrator must enable searching for your SharePoint site collection. Also, they must setup and make sure the SharePoint search service is running.

[Here is another SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887024/how-to-enable-search-in-documents-in-sharepoint-2010) where they ask a similar question: [How to enable search in documents in SharePoint 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887024/how-to-enable-search-in-documents-in-sharepoint-2010)

The answer points to [this article: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/3531/sharepoint-2010-search-not-working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887024/how-to-enable-search-in-documents-in-sharepoint-2010)

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and response.  I will contact my admit.